# Series of books about a female wolf/alien

Tags: story-identification, books

So years ago when I was in middle school my friend handed me a VERY thick small print paper back book and said "here, read this".

So I did. And I loved it. I read the rest of the books in the series (can't remember how many there were) and I loved those too.

I have since lost contact with the friend, but I still vaguely remember the books. I would like to re-read them because I enjoyed them and would like for some of my memories to make sense.

All I can remember from the books are as follows:

- Pretty sure it was an adult book.
- The main character (at least in the first one) was a female, she wasn't human but like a wolf or.. Something.. She was an alien I'm pretty sure.
- She was a slave of sorts and had to wear an electronic collar or sorts. 
  She was trained to.. Fight? Like for sport in an arena? She wore a snug suit of types that like helped her or something. I can't remember.
- She injured her leg somehow which made it impossible for her to be used to fight any more so she was then used in a lab.
- She was tested on and bred in the lab for her offspring to also be tested on.
- Pretty sure she got her pups out some how and ended up dying I think? I can't remember.

Does anyone know what I'm talking about? 
Edit: I'm not sure if all my memories are from the first book or not. I know the bit about the lab was the last book. I think

Comment: I tried to write a more descriptive title, but feel free to change it to something else.

Comment: Lol thank you <3 I have been on so many different forums looking for this book, I got tired of trying to come up with titles to my question 

Comment: Haha no problem. :) People around here are good at finding books, so maybe somebody will find the series. And welcome to the site.

Comment: So how many years ago?

Comment: Well, I think it was 7 years ago. And I'm not sure but I think the book wasn't new. Pretty she got it from a second hand store or maybe from her brother. Heck, she might have gotten it new. I don't know

Comment: Actually, now that I really think about it, it's been 8-9 years ago.